# Google Checkout callback issue

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, google-checkout

I am trying to (using a sandbox account) sell items using google checkout. I am displaying a form to the user which results in a buy now button

```
<form method="POST" action="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/api/checkout/v2/checkoutForm/Merchant/..." accept-charset="utf-8">  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Test"/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_description_1" value="An item "/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1"/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="item_price_1" value="1.50"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_currency_1" value="GBP"/>    
    <input type="hidden" name="_charset_"/>   
    <input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.continue-shopping-url" value="redirect to this url"/>
    <input type="image" name="Google Checkout" alt="Fast checkout through Google" src="http://sandbox.google.com/checkout/buttons/checkout.gif?merchant_id=....&w=180&h=46&style=white&variant=text&loc=en_US" height="46" width="180"/>  
</form>
```

On the google seller account i am setting the url to be called back too. In this instance i am using the php file from the google docs example

```
// Include Google Checkout PHP Client Library
include ("GlobalAPIFunctions.php");

// Include Response Message Processor
include ("ResponseHandlerAPIFunctions.php");

// Retrieve the XML sent in the HTTP POST request to the ResponseHandler
$xml_response = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

// Get rid of PHP's magical escaping of quotes 
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $xml_response = stripslashes($xml_response);
}

// Log the XML received in the HTTP POST request
LogMessage($GLOBALS["logfile"], $xml_response);

/*
 * Call the ProcessXmlData function, which is defined in
 * ResponseHandlerAPIFunctions.php. The ProcessXmlData will route 
 * the XML data to the function that handles the particular type
 * of XML message contained in the POST request.
 */
ProcessXmlData($xml_response);
```

The issue is, as soon as i buy an item i get no call back whatsoever. No error message, no nothing so how can i see what is going on? Hopefully someone could help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your **Sandbox** [Integration Console](https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/sell/settings?section=IntegrationConsole) for errors (if any) - just making sure that you are referring to your sandbox account (sandbox and production accounts are distinct)

> On the google seller account i am setting the url to be called back ***too***

***"too"*** - just making sure. There is only **one** place where you set the **API Callback URL** - and that is in your [Account Integration Settings](https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/sell/settings?section=Integration) (so there is no "too").

> `<input type="hidden" name="checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.continue-shopping-url" value="redirect to this url"/>`

Again, just clarifying that you are not referring to the above as the **callback api url**. The above is the link presented to a buyer *after purchase* (it's just a link back to your web site). It is **not** the callback api url.

Comment: Not sure if you will end up seeing this but after taking your advice i found the error; it was `We encountered an error trying to access your server at .......php -- the error we got is java.io.IOException: Error 'CLOSED' connecting to url '......php` not to sure why this is so but will have a look. Thanks